# Trouble in Installing Stagehand

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

I am unable to find out the reason for this error. 
VS CODE VERSION: 1.39.2

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the bin directory from dart-sdk on you Path which are a Windows Environment Variable. On Windows 10 you can click on the Windows key and write "Edit the system environment variables" and in the following GUI click "Environment Variables..." to go to the GUI "Environment Variables".

Here you find the `Path` variable under the System variables and add a new entry which points to the bin directory from the dart-sdk you have downloaded (e.g. `C:\Tools\dart-sdk\bin`). If you use an older version of Windows you need to separate each entry in the path with ;

Comment: I don't understand why I have to do this for working on dart files. Because my flutter projs are working correctly ! Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Well, I don't use VSCode or Flutter. But I have seen this problem before using cmd and powershell and it looks like VSCode are running a PowerShell in your case. Since PowerShell are using the Path variable then Dart are properly needed to be on the Path.